# How can I set cookie on Python Scrapy http request?

Tags: python, cookies, scrapy

I have below code in python scrapy to crawl a website with a `cookie` in the request header.

```
headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36',
            'cookie': 'visid_incap_1388804=z0HpykCPTPOl91x1ZVgBin26ql4AAAAAQUIPAAAAAAAP3GOgoT20BZ/L8SMtjnDl; _gcl_au=1.1.924686404.1588247167; _ga=GA1.3.462736265.1588247167; _hjid=6cf736f7-6277-4326-9175-f50c1a373252; _fbp=fb.2.1588247167593.544254491; __gads=ID=a40d8232240136b3:T=1588247168:S=ALNI_MYjyYGgkvkfTsidqhzhkwQuLC9niQ; oth.sid=s%3AUDaLYz674-QEw8q_F0EBBqKxc1Fq8O6y.qs6ZhO%2B9TEJJgoYyDloSOD%2F0LXJOyiZ2CoMRbNjhXyc; nlbi_1388804=BeWWYqa/eg5iFqlA7jV9NwAAAACu/PEk+hkcYO5CjDDQsQRb; _gid=GA1.3.1321216902.1591447562; incap_ses_312_1388804=WK0DD6USuDnBjixreXJUBKuI3F4AAAAA6s4uCe5fmSv6TCkCePRobg==',
            'authority': 'www.onthehouse.com.au',
            'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
            'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
            'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6,de;q=0.5',
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "pragma": "no-cache",
            "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
            "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
            "sec-fetch-site": "none",
            "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
            "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
            "referrerPolicy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade"
        }
        yield scrapy.http.Request(urls[0], headers=headers)
```

However, in the log I can see below `Set-Cookie` which looks different than the one in my request:

```
DEBUG:scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies:Received cookies from: <200 https://www.onthehouse.com.au/property-for-rent/vic/aspendale-gardens-3195>
Set-Cookie: visid_incap_1388804=RwmeJ/64TviesvhgjXZIQSDK3F4AAAAAQUIPAAAAAAD4Pp0pBTdJ3taXYbWHPW7O; expires=Mon, 07 Jun 2021 07:18:25 GMT; HttpOnly; path=/; Domain=.onthehouse.com.au

Set-Cookie: incap_ses_312_1388804=zn6FMsJVp1kAazNreXJUBHTK3F4AAAAAlo68QiIx5K4rzyjwMjMGaA==; path=/; Domain=.onthehouse.com.au

2020-06-07 21:07:33 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies] DEBUG: Received cookies from: <200 https://www.onthehouse.com.au/property-for-rent/vic/aspendale-gardens-3195>
Set-Cookie: visid_incap_1388804=RwmeJ/64TviesvhgjXZIQSDK3F4AAAAAQUIPAAAAAAD4Pp0pBTdJ3taXYbWHPW7O; expires=Mon, 07 Jun 2021 07:18:25 GMT; HttpOnly; path=/; Domain=.onthehouse.com.au

Set-Cookie: incap_ses_312_1388804=zn6FMsJVp1kAazNreXJUBHTK3F4AAAAAlo68QiIx5K4rzyjwMjMGaA==; path=/; Domain=.onthehouse.com.au
```

I wonder how I should set the cookie in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `cookies` parameter for your `Request`:

```
Request(
    url="http://www.example.com",
    cookies={
        'visid_incap_1388804': 'z0HpykCPTPOl91x1ZVgBin26ql4AAAAAQUIPAAAAAAAP3GOgoT20BZ/L8SMtjnDl',
        'oth.sid': 's%3AUDaLYz674-QEw8q_F0EBBqKxc1Fq8O6y.qs6ZhO%2B9TEJJgoYyDloSOD%2F0LXJOyiZ2CoMRbNjhXyc',},
)
```